# Importing dateutil package in ironpython script

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I try to import dateutil package with my IronPython script but I get an error `unexpected token '='`. The error comes from this file: ...\Python36\Lib\string.py.

My script is executed by `ScriptEngine` class from Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting and it goes like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages')
from dateutil.parser import *
class PythonCaller():
    def Call(self):
        return parse('2000-01-01')
```

But everything is ok when I do it this way:

```
 ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
 start.FileName = "...\\Python36\\python.exe";
 start.Arguments = "...\\Files\\pythonExample.py";
 start.UseShellExecute = false;
 start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
 {
     using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
     {
         string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
         Console.Write(result);
     }
 }
 var a = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

and my pythonExample file is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib')
sys.path.append(r'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages')
from dateutil.parser import *
print(parse('2000-01-01'))
```

How to import dateutil in `IronPython` file and execute it by ScriptEngine  in C#? Is it possible to import external python libraries in that way?

Comment: The released versions of IronPython are only compatible with 2.7.x of Python. We are working on 3.x compatibility.